# Average of words in a sentence?

Tags: python, list, split

```
print 'The average amount of words in the sentence is' ,average, 'words'
```

I just cant get this to work

Comment: First, you've got a `for word in words:` loop, but you're not doing anything with `word`. Why are you calling `len(words)` instead of, say, calling `len(word)`?

Comment: Second, in order to average things, you have to add them up. You can keep a running total as you go along, or you can stick them in a list and call `sum` on it later, or anything else you can think of, but you have to do _something_.

Comment: Then, once you have that total, you just need to divide it by the number of words, and you've got the average. You should be able to figure out how to do that once you've got the total working.

Comment: Think about the mathematical definition of average - **the sum of the individual values** divided by the **number of values**. "Values" in this case are the lengths of each word.

Comment: Can one of you please re-write the actual form of being able to count each amount of words in the list, then adding each amount of letters into an average. I'm very new so I apologize for the crude looking code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should sum the individual characters and  divid by the number of words in your list.

Words are splited by space (but you should think about the different scenarios). `nbrChar` is variable that is used to count characters in all words.

```
from __future__ import division
sentence = raw_input ("Please write a sentence for it to be counted and averaged:")

words = sentence.split(" ") #You should split words by space

nbrChar, average=0, .0

for word in words:
    nbrChar+= len(word)

average= nbrChar // len(words) 

print 'The average amount of words in the sentence is' ,average, 'words'
```